# Adjust BibLaTeX style - Number of displayed editors

Tags: biblatex

The attached MWE gives the following result

> Author, A., B. Author, C. Author, et al. (1992). “Title”. In: Booktitle, ed. by A. Editor, B. Editor, and C. Editor. Vol. 59. Springer, New York.

What I'd like to have is

> Author, A., B. Author, C. Author, et al. (1992). “Title”. In: Booktitle, ed. by A. Editor, et al. Vol. 59. Springer, New York.

i.e. display only the first editor followed by et al. while keeping the first three authors before et al.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[    
    backend=biber,      % use biber backend or bibtex
    bibencoding=utf8,   % use auto file encode
    style=authoryear,   % use alphabetic (or numeric) bib style
    natbib=true,            % allow natbib commands
    hyperref=true,      % activate hyperref support
    backref=false,      % activate backrefs
    isbn=true,              % don't show isbn tags
    url=false,              % don't show url tags
    doi=true,                   % show doi tags
    urldate=long,           % display type for dates
    maxnames=2,             % max number of names in text ??
    minnames=1,             % min number of names in text ??
    maxbibnames=4,      % max number of names in bibliography
    minbibnames=3,      % number of names in bibliography (bevor et al)
    maxcitenames=2,     % max number of names in text ??
    mincitenames=1,     % max number of names in text ??
    dashed=false,           % do not replace same author with dash 
    useprefix=false,    % ?
    firstinits=true,    % abbreviate first names
    uniquename=init,    % otherwise option conflict with firstinits=true
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{test,
    year={1992},
    booktitle={Booktitle},
    volume={59},
    editor={Editor, A. and Editor, B. and Editor, C.},
    title="{Title}",
    publisher={Springer, New York},
    author={Author, A. and Author, B. and Author, C. and Author, D. and Author, E.},
}
\end{filecontents}

\newbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
    \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {   \setunit{\addcomma\space}
        \usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
        \setunit{\addspace}%
        \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
        \clearname{editor}%
        \newunit}%
    \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
    \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: For your first request you could either patch the bibdriver with `xpatch` to have a `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` instead of the normal `\newunit\newblock` at the appropriate place, or try some tricks with inserting the `\setunit` command right into the `byeditor` macro.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot for your comment! With a bit trial and error I found the right place to insert the `\setunit{\addcomma\space}`. So only the problem with the number of editors remains.

Comment: Great, I think if you move the `\setunit{\addcomma\space}` bit further up, you can get even better results: `\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}` (line breaks not to scale)

Comment: One solution (not the nicest, I think) is to use the second optional argument to `\printnames` to specify the number of names printed, since we already modify `byeditor+others` we only need `\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor][1-1]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}` (line breaks, again, not to scale).

Comment: The drawback of that solution is that `editora`, `translator`s etc. are treated differently: they still get all their names displayed, a change for those would require some more code.

Comment: @moewe Thank you so much for your comments! That is exactly what I wanted. Would you be so kind to convert your comment into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the second optional argument of `\printnames` to specify the number of names printed, the syntax is `[<start>-<stop>]`, so in your case

```
\printnames[byeditor][1-1]{editor}
```

The relevant occurrence is in `byeditor+others`

```
\renewbibmacro*{byeditor+others}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \ifnameundef{editor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byeditor][1-1]{editor}%
     \clearname{editor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byeditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{bytranslator+others}}
```